# DNS migration P2P by filtering using existing zone files

Tags: dns

We want to migrate DNS server( P2P). The zone file is very huge and I want to remove unused or wrong entry from old existing zone files to make it clean.

Is there any way to validate the zone file record in bulk ??

Comment: Hi, and welcome to superuser. Although you do ask an interesting question, I believe more info is needed here before a proper answer can be provided by the community. I recommend adding additional info such as format of the zone file, in addition to the actual amount of entries to help quantify how "huge" it is, considering the size might impact which method would be the most convenient.

Comment: You need to define "unused" or "wrong entry". What is the criteria a tool would need to use to filter those out? Also what does P2P have to do with DNS?